# How do I create a tab in salesforce linking another salesforce object

Tags: custom-object, tab

Currently I have a review object with the fields related and details, I want to add another tab linking to another salesforce object that is in my schema. How do I do that?[image]

Comment: If I understand, you want to add a new tab with only one related list to a specific object ? Is your object **Review** has any link with this object?

Comment: @Badbaxx No. I actually want the review to be a tab under case where case is a parent while review is a child (So a master-detail relationship?). This is because I want every case to have a review. How might I do that?

Answer (score 1):

View a Review record, and click on ⚙️ > Edit Page. Click on the tab set, and add the new tab using the menu on the right. Click on the new tab to activate it. Then, find the Related Record standard component, and drag it into the tab. Then, use the right-hand panel to select Cases. You may need to create some new Actions for creating and editing a case. Once everything is done, Save the changes, then Activate the new Page as the system default, or for each profile you want to use the page on.