# How do I put Salesforce child details into tabs?

Tags: relationships, related-list, master-detail, tab

My question actually comprises of two sections. I have two objects namely cases and reviews. Firstly, I want to build a one-to-one relationship between cases and reviews where cases is the parent and reviews is the child. Secondly, I want to be able to be able to update the reviews detail in a tab in the parent component. How do I do that?

Currently, my cases and reviews are in a master detail relationship and I am able to add it as a related list.[image]

However, what I really want is to add what is within the review object (as shown below) into one of the case tabs since only one review is supposed to be linked to the parent.[image]

Currently, I only know how to separate part of the case detail into another tab as shown in the Other tab.[image]

How might I replicate what is in the Other tab for my review tab?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Lookup field on Case called "Review". Then, set up an automation that populates the case's Review field when a new review is created. You can then use this lookup field to use the exact same steps as you used in the [previous Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/383468/2984).

[image: Sample Flow to Update Case with Review ID]